# Getting data from firebase Database

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, this is how my json database looks

[image: **JSON**]

I need to grab information from this

[image: **section**]

The problem is that all the children of this element have the null value.(I am only interested in their key which is represented by push ids)
My program should return a `list` of the keys.(or part of them). Any ideas on how do I do it in android studio ?

Here is my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH3v0.png) that gets executed to retrieve..still not working..any ideas on what am I doing wrong..?

Comment: its not a null value, but a string based on characters of null. Putting null against a node in firebase deletes it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataSnapshot.getKey()` to get the key. You can loop through all the children by using:

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String key = childSnapshot.getKey();
}
```

Comment: The following code is executed to try and retrieve data: DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("postHistory");
            ref.orderByValue().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String key = childSnapshot.getKey();
                        Log.d("SOME POST: ", key);
                    }
                } I still don't get any result..

Comment: DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("postHistory"); ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { String key = childSnapshot.getKey(); Log.d("SOME POST: ", key); } }